# get sender's IP

Tags: java, http, jsp, request, response

I have a tomcat application running on port no 443 ,
This application receives request from multiple application servers for password authentication .
i e . users from multiple applications access this application(on 443) for password authentication on web browser , and are sent back after authentication

By goal is to bind my application (running on 443 ) for specific servers .(make inaccessible from the world .)

I have tried getting ip of the system from which i am getting the request , but had no luck .

```
 request.getRemoteAddr();
 request.getRemoteHost();
```

returns clients IP on which the webpage is open

I need the ip of the server from which request is sent to me

I also tried doing

```
request.getServerName();
```

but i am getting the ip of my own server not the sender

Comment: Are you saying these application servers act as proxies, that the end user never connects to your server?

Comment: Then the sender is a client... I do not fully understand the scenario: client sends username + password to e.g. ServerA. ServerA retrieves the information and forwards it to your Tomcat app. Your app sends back a response to ServerA which then forwards back to client. Is this correct?

Comment: end user is only able to see the password page . like the way credit card transactions take place these days . You get your banks page to enter transaction passsword

Comment: Ok, so your app is some kind SSO authentication proxy?

Comment: Then there is no secure way for you to derieve the server that redirected to your application. You could try the [HTTP referrer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referrer). If you need a more reliable mechanism, you must negotiate tokens between the other servers and your app.

Answer (score 1):

you might want to use

```
request.getServerName();
```

to determinate whom the client wanted to address.

Comment: This returns ip of my own sever (tomcat)

Comment: are you using a webserver that does rewriting of requests (like apache and mod_rewrite?) If yes: You are lost if you want to do that only in java. If no: please provide technical data on how the requests comes to your tomcat (including every point where that information traverses a server you control)